# How to redirect to another page in GWT application

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

- I have a client class `UserLogin` which also represents my entrypoint . I ask for a password and login to the user, I make my server side check and I get a response in the form of a string representing an `xml file` that I must parse and generate the widget with the coded information this `xml` .
- I'm stuck here: if the user is recognized , I want to redirect to a second page "home" which will present the user with the component provides the answer. Only I do not know how to do that normally in class that generates the home I have to have the `onModuleLoad ()` method that will parse the response from the server and display the desired elements.

Comment: are you want to redirect to some other page or want to navigate from one screen to other screen in the same page?

Comment: GWT only ever has one "page" so I assume you want to show another presenter? I use GWTP (http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/) and I highly recommend it if you have the time.

Comment: yes , i want want to navigate from one screen to another . I used RootPanel.get().add( new screen()) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT is Single Page Web Application,to Navigating one Screen to other screen just clear layout Container and add the newly created Container to `RootPanel`.See example code,

```
HorizontalPanel hp=new HorizontalPanel();
Button btn=new Button("Login");
hp.add(new TextBox());
hp.add(new PasswordTextBox());
hp.add(btn);
RootPanel.get().add(hp);

btn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
RootPanel.get().clear();
RootPanel.get().add(new screen());
}
});
```